# Sitecore development and demo servers

Tags: sitecore

I'm attempting to get an understanding of what is a best practice / recommended setup for moving information between multiple Sitecore installations.  I have a copy of Sitecore setup on my machine for development.  We need a copy of the system setup for demonstration to the client and for people to enter in content prelaunch.  How should I set things up so I people can enter content / modify the demonstration version of the site and still allow me to continue development on my local machine and publish my updates without overwriting changes between the systems?  Or is this not the correct approach for me to be taking?

I believe that the 'publishing target' feature is what I need to use, but as this is my first project working with Sitecore and so I am looking for practical experience on how to manage this workflow.

Comment: Update: I've been in touch with the Sitecore support team and I am going to have a call with them on February 1st to discuss this.  I will post what I learn from the call following.

Comment: The recommendation from the Sitecore team was use the Packages feature.  I am developing in Sitecore 6.3 for future reference, since I did not mention version information in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you looks at the [staging module](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Staging.aspx) if you need to publish to multiple targets from the same instance, i.e. publish content from one tree over a firewall to a development site, to a QA site, etc.

If you're just migrating content from one instance to another piecemeal, you can use [Sitecore packages](http://sdn.sitecore.net/End%20User/Package_Designer_SC6.aspx) which are standard tools to move content. The packages serialize the content to XML and zip it up and allow you to install them in other instances.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I'll look at the at the staging module.

Answer (score 4):

Nathan,
You didn't specify what version of Sitecore, but I will assume 6.01+

Leveraging publishing targets will allow you to 'publish' your development Sitecore tree (or sub-trees) from your development environment to the destination, such as your QA server. However, there is potential that you publish /sitecore/content/home/* and then you wipe out your production content!

[Mark mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834292/sitecore-development-and-demo-servers#4837137) using "Sitecore Packages" to move your content (as well as templates, layout items, etc...) over, which is the traditional way of moving items between environments. Also, you didn't specify what version of Sitecore you are using, but the Staging Module is not needed for Sitecore 6.3+. The Staging Module was generally used to keep file systems in sync and to clear the cache of Content Delivery servers.

However, the one piece of the puzzle that is missing here is that, you will still need to update your code (.jpg, .css, .js, .dll, .etc) on the QA box.

The optimal solution would be to have your Sitecore items (templates, layout item, rendering items, and developer owned content items) in Source control right alongside your ASP.NET Web Application and any class library projects you may have. At a basic level, you can do this using built in  "Serialization" features of Sitecore. Lars Nielsen wrote an [article touching on this](http://www.sitecore.net/en/Community/Business-Blogs/Technical-Trends/Posts/2010/06/Team-Development-With-Sitecore.aspx).

To take this to the next level, you would use a tool such as [Team Development for Sitecore](http://TeamDevelopmentForSitecore.com). This tool will allow you to easily bring your Sitecore items into Visual Studio and treat them as code. At this point you could setup automated builds, or continuous integration, so that your code and Sitecore items, are automatically pushed to your QA environment. There are also configuration options to handle the scenario of keeping production content in place while still deploying developer owned items.

Comment: Thank you for the insight on this.  I do not have a terribly complex project, so I am going to use the packages route for updating items.